# Contextual Filter (Author's Username) Multiple usernames

Tags: feeds, views

I'm setting up a custom Views RSS Feed that looks something like this.
[image: snapshot]

The problem is, when I add one user name as a filter, it works but anything after it, the view will not show the post of the other user. Ex: If my name is X and I put X in for the filter, it shows X's post but if I put in X/Y, only X's posts will show.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the "Allow multiple values" option of the contextual filter set (it is in the "MORE" collapsible fieldset).

Then you have to separate the names with a plus symbol (+) or a comma (,).

If you separate with a slash views will treat it as 2 separate arguments and your view only has one argument.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Also, with the XML RSS Feed, is it possible that I create a block or widget where you just plug in the names of the users you want to see, and it creates an rss feed automagically?

Comment: If you also have a related non-rss display for that view you can use exposed filters on that view and then the rss feed icon link that comes with that view will inherit any exposed filters the user has set. Alternatively you could create a custom block that has a simple form with a text field and a submit button, then when the user submits it you could redirect to the rss feed. - You could also have a block with a text field and a link/button for the user to click, and use javascript on the button/link so that when it's clicked it gets the field value and uses it to direct the user to the rss.

Comment: Using your second idea, how would I create a block that has a field where you put the names of the users you want in, comma seperated and from there append it to the rss feed link? Is there a module I can edit?

Comment: I haven't really investigated it but off the top of my head no. It would be a relatively small amount of code but you would have to crete it custom.

Comment: Hm. Coding :/ Thanks for the help, I'll try to meddle with it :D